# Convert function string argument into variable

Tags: php, arguments

I want to convert function string argument into array. so if I set `'user'` than eventually in function I want to convert it to `$user` as soon as function start.

**function**

```
function get_item($object, $key)
{
    //I want to convert 'user' string in '$user' variable

    echo empty($object->$key) ? 'do_stuffs' : 'dont_do_stuffs';
}
```

**usage**

```
get_item('user', 'id');
```

I have tried something like

```
function get_item($object, $key)
{
    $$object = $object //this is not working

    echo empty($object->$key) ? 'do_stuffs' : 'dont_do_stuffs';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below:

```
function get_item($object, $key) {
  // if there are no other code in this function, then `$$object` will not be defined.
  // you can't get $user from the outside the function scope.
  $value =  $$object->{$key};
  echo empty($value) ? 'do_stuffs' : 'dont_do_stuffs';
}
```

You are using variable variables, in most case, it's not a good idea.

Comment: @JatinSoni See my comment.

Comment: I see. Actually I am trying to get an object from outside the function. So this means it will not work? but when I passed variable itself `$user`  it is working without any error

Comment: @JatinSoni Yes, you have to pass it to the function, or using global variable (which is strongly not recommended.)